# Accessing value from expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
public Method1(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> valueToCompare) {
    //Examine expression
}

public Method1(TProperty valueToCompare) : this(x => valueToCompare) {}
```

and i run them like this

```
Method1(x => 1);
```

and

```
Method1(1);
```

If i examine the expression when the first overload is called then I get a constant expression. However when I examine the second one I get a member expression.

The question is how do I get access to the value '1' no matter which overload i call.

**Update1:** 
I used to do this until I realised the didn't both return the same thing.

```
if (valueToCompare.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
{
    var constant = valueToCompare.Body as ConstantExpression;
    ValueToCompare = constant != null ? (TProperty)constant.Value : default(TProperty);
}
```

What will i get if I compile it?

Tried to do this but it didn't work.

```
if (ValueToCompare .Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess) {
   var member = ValueToCompare .Body as MemberExpression;
   if (member.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
   {
       ConstantExpression constant = member.Expression as ConstantExpression;
       ValueToCompare = constant.Value;
   }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you happy to just compile the expression and run it? That would seem the easiest solution to me...

Alternatively, you could make your overload taking a `TProperty` explicitly construct a constant expression, rather than using a lambda expression. It really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

As an example of the latter approach, you'd write something like (untested):

```
public void Method1(TProperty valueToCompare) : this(x => valueToCompare)
{
     Expression constant = Expression.Constant(valueToCompare,
                                               typeof(TProperty));
     ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T),
                                                          "t");
     Expression lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TProperty>> (constant,
                                                                parameter);
     Method1(lambda);
}
```

Comment: Seems to have worked. Thanks heaps.
Also what is the ParameterExpression for and why is it set to "t"?

Comment: The ParameterExpression is just to represent the parameter for the lambda expression; "t" is just the name. In other words, it's building an expression like (t => 1)

Comment: Thought it might have been. Cool. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is how do I get access to
>   the value '1' no matter which overload
>   i call.

You don't, as you've discovered.  Not without compiling and executing the expression tree to produce its value.

Remember, the **purpose** of an expression tree is **to capture the compile-time information about the expression and present it at runtime**, not **the runtime value that evaluating the expression produces**.

In your example, you have two different expressions -- one is a constant, one is an outer variable of a closure.  Outer variables are represented by fields, so you get a field access expression. **The expression tree you get represents the expression that you put in the lambda.**

Perhaps you can describe what you are really trying to do; there is probably a better way. If what you want is the *value*, why do you need an expression tree at all?